# Reason for Value Coercion

Tags: wpf, bind

Is the reason for value coercion to avoid infinite recursion by causing related values to update without triggering their binds or OnUpdate methods?

Nothing really explains this, because what I'm working on has a ton of flags to skip over callback updates so I break such a recursion.

Comment: I think it's mainly to **ensure a value stays within a range**. e.g. if you have a dynamic DatePicker and you have a Min/Max specified, you coerce the value to stay within the Min/Max date range.

Comment: I know you can coerce to ensure conditions. I'm just wondering if coerce prevents feedback. Like if you set Value within CoerceMaxValue, then Value would normally feedback and CoerceValue, but if Coercion stops this feedback, then I can make use of it in a way to prevent my infinite recursion other than lambdas and flags.